# How do I enable DMA on a SATA controller?

Tags: windows-8, 64-bit, dma

I don't see any section "IDE ATA/ATAPI controllers" in device manager:

[image]

What does this mean? and Can I know on which devices DMA can be enabled?

Comment: From what I can make out from your picture, do you use a HP Envy M6-1214TX? According to the specification it has a 1TB SATA 5400rpm hard disk so I would assume DMA is already on...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your M6-1214TX *doesn't have* an IDE interface. It uses SATA to connect the internal disk, just like most other computers made in the past 7–10 years, and SATA always uses DMA; you couldn't even turn it off.

Not sure about where it shows up in Device Manager, though. It's possible that Win8 lists SATA controllers under "Storage controllers" next to other types (SCSI and such).

Comment: Came across this while troubleshooting a Creative soundcard. Their [support page](http://support.creative.com/kb/ShowArticle.aspx?sid=46913) mentions drives that support DMA but no mention of SATA, where as you say it is enabled by default. Unfortunately some of us are still in a bit of a time warp. :(

Answer (score 2):

Why would you even think DMA is *not* enabled? To see how your disk drive is connected, use the “By connection” view and search for it there. If I were to venture a guess, I’d say it’s a Memory Technology Device, a type of embedded flash memory.